# how to get exact month difference in Joda-Time after adding no.of days

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to find no.of months between two dates. any help appreciated. I'm using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for the below example.

```
DateMidnight start = new DateMidnight(new Date()); 
DateMidnight dtEndDate  = start.plusDays(11);   //adding Days

int months = Months.monthsBetween(start, dtEndDate).getMonths();

System.out.println("Months between " +
                    start.toString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " and " +
                    dtEndDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " = " +
                    months + " month(s)");
```

The above code returning '0' for 2013-Feb-18 to 2013-Mar-01

I can't add +1 to months as i need to find difference in same month, also i need to find difference between two elapsed periods i.e between '2012-Dec-04' and '2013-Jan-06' should return -1;

```
scenario1:

date1:  2013-02-18
    date1.plusDays(11);
date2:  2013-03-01
Output : 0 month(s)   //but I need as 1 Month

scenario2:
date1:  2013-02-18
    date1.plusDays(1);
date2:  2013-02-19
Output : 0 month(s)   //returns correctly exactly what I need

scenario3:
date1:  2013-03-18
date2:  2013-02-19
Output should be : -1 month(s)
```

Comment: What exactly is a "month" by your definition? Is it "how many times does this span of time cross a month-of-year boundary"? Would 2013-02-28 (end of February) to 2013-03-01 (beginning of March) count as 1 month?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the day of month to `1` for both dates before comparing:

```
startModified = start.withDayOfMonth(1); 
endModified = end.withDayOfMonth(1);
int months = Months.monthsBetween(startModified, endModified).getMonths();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, is there any difference if i use DateTime instead of DateMidnight, when i used DateMidnight its working but not with DateTime

Comment: Then your dates must be having have a time component. `DateMidnight` will normalize all times to midnight. If you use `DateTime` and you have different times in your dates, it will alter the result because the number of months between `1st March 2012 4 PM` and `1st April 2012 1 PM` will be less than one month (because it will be exactly one month only at `4 PM`).

Comment: thanks again for explaining. I dont know why the following giving '0' months   DateTime start = new DateTime("2013-02-22T16:15:53.113Z");
        DateTime end = new DateTime("2013-03-28T00:00:00.000Z");

Comment: Because once you set day of month to `1`, it becomes `2013-02-01 4 PM` to `2013-03-01 midnight`, so there is 16 more hours to go before a full month has passed, therefore months is `0`.

Comment: The "midnight"-related methods in Joda-Time are no longer recommended by their creators. Use the newer [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) method instead.